# Implementing malloc with gcc in an arm7 problems : malloc return NULL

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, arm

I am adding malloc support in my firmware and I think I'm missing something!

I use code sourcery g++ lite library for an arm7tdmi processor and my code is based on the example found in this link : http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/stellaris_arm_cortex-m3_microcontroller/f/473/t/44452.aspx#539503

I added my version of _sbrk :

```
char * _sbrk(int incr)
{
    //extern char _end; /* Defined by the linker */
    static char *heap_end;
    char *prev_heap_end;
    register char* stackPtr;

    if (heap_end == 0)
    {
        // first allocation
        heap_end =HEAP_END;
    }

    prev_heap_end = heap_end;

    // get current stack pointer
    asm ("mov %0, sp\n\t" : "=r" (stackPtr) );



    if (heap_end + incr > stackPtr) {
        return NULL;// error - no more memory
        //write (1, "Heap and stack collision\n", 25);
        //abort ();
    }
    heap_end += incr;
    return (char*) prev_heap_end;
}
```

Some defines used by sbrk :

```
#define SDRAM_SIZE 16*1024*1024        
#define HEAP_BASE  _ebss
#define HEAP_END ((_stext + SDRAM_SIZE) -1)
#define HEAP_SIZE HEAP_END - HEAP_BASE
```

(_ebss and _stext come from my linker file)

Here's my main where I did a simple malloc/free call :

```
void C_main ( void)
{
  char * testmalloc=0;
  /* Initialize "Heap Descriptor" pointer */
  pHeapDescriptor =  __rt_embeddedalloc_init ((void*)HEAP_BASE,HEAP_SIZE);
  testmalloc = malloc(2048);
  free(testmalloc);
}
```

I run this program in step mode. When I call malloc, it eventually call my _sbrk implementation, the return value (prev_heap_end) have an expected value, but when the program return to the main, the testmalloc value is NULL (somewhere in the gcc library, the prev_heap_end is lost).

Does someone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Don't know if that will help, but this is my gcc compilation parameter :

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -march=armv4t -mcpu=arm7tdmi -dp -c 
-Wa,-adhlns="../../Base/Lib/Pa/main.o.lst" -fmessage-length=0 
-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss -MMD -MP -MF"../../Base/Lib/Pa/main.d" 
-MT"../../Base/Lib/Pa/main.d" -fpic -mlittle-endian -Wall -g3 -gdwarf-2  
../../Base/Hardintrf/Mezzanine/main.c -o"../../Base/Lib/Pa/main.o"
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: your first global vars are not initialized, so they might not be guaranteed to be NULL initially like you assume.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @SB may have a point, although the static variable should go into the BSS where it will be zero-initialised, but it's worth checking. Another problem is that I think you should initialize heap_end to HEAP_BASE, not HEAP_END, or else it will start the heap outside of memory, no?

Comment: heap_end is in the BSS. You are right for heap_end, it have to be to HEAP_BASE, now it works great! You can repeat this in an answer so I can mark it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (heap_end == 0)
{
    // first allocation
    heap_end = HEAP_END;
}
```

This should read:

```
if (heap_end == 0)
{
    // first allocation
    heap_end = HEAP_BASE;
}
```

So you don't start your heap at the end of your heap... You might want to think up a better name for that variable then heap_end to avoid this confusion in the first place.

Also you don't need to use the register modifier to make your inline assembly work correctly. The compiler is smart enough to do that for you.